# Objective-C: How do I do console input?

Tags: objective-c

How do I get an NSString from console input, and then try to cast it into an int?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read in a `char*` string from console (scanf or whatever), like you would in a regular C program. Then, create an `NSString` object from it using `stringFromCString:withEncoding:`. Finally, use `NSString`'s `integerValue` function to get it's numerical value.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it directly with scanf. Example

```
int number = 0;
scanf("%d", &number);
```