# Taking Command Line Input in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway we can take input from command line in Objective-C, the way we can take in C/C++?

```
int inputVariableName;

cin >> inputVariableName;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scanf("%i", userInput);
```

just as you would in c

To get Objective-C objects from the input, simple convert them after reading them in:

NSNumber * number = [nsnumber numberwithint:useriput];

Comment: But i have another question, though it can solve my problem by now but if have an Object which has NSString or NSNumber objects within it, how i can take input for them? Since there is there no way scanf can handle these kind of objects?

Comment: I think i got answer to my second question on the following ur:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493688/objective-c-how-do-i-do-console-input

Comment: Shouldn't scanf("%i", userInput) read scanf("%i", &userInput)?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Compile your code as Objective-C++.

This is typically as easy as renaming the file from having a .m suffix to a .mm suffix.

Documentation is included with the Xcode tools as to the details of Objective-C++.

Comment: I don't know about Objective-C++ but is there any native way in Objective-C?

Comment: Objective-C++ is native Objective-C.  But, yes, you can do this in pure Objective-C.  See the NSFileHandle class.

Comment: @Dmitry What doesn't work?  Compiling the code as C++ works fine has been supported for over a decade.  And it includes the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

As bbum mentioned, you can use NSFileHandle to get access to stdin.  If you just want to read the command line arguments, you can get them from [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments].  It's also worthwhile to know what else NSProcessInfo can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

**Command line input with spaces**

```
    char textInput[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", textInput);

    NSString* userInput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:textInput];
    NSLog(@"\n%@\n%@", @"Hello, World.", userInput);
```

Input text with white spaces, 1000 is input character limit.